# What would prevent a .BAT file from being run on a mapped drive?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

In WinXP SP3, I have a .BAT file on a mapped drive. When I try to run this .BAT file (or even right click->edit) it gives me:

```
---------------------------
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This happens with any .BAT file, no matter what is within the file. If the file is on my local computer (like C:) it will run just fine. If someone else runs it from another computer (on the same mapped drive), it runs just fine.

I have full permissions on the drive; I can edit/delete/save/write/create in that folder and/or .BAT file and I've ruled out permissions being the issue.

It seems like a security prevention, but I can't tell what it would be. It would have to be something on my PC, but I don't use any 3rd party software.

What would cause this error?

Comment: What is your antivirus?

Comment: @francisswest I just double checked, I don't have one. The only thing I have is "Intel Management and Security Status"

Comment: Are you an admin on the machine as a whole?  Have you tried to run said batch file as an admin? (Right click, run as... or hold shift, right click, run as....been a while since I was on XP...)

Comment: @francisswest I am admin, yes. I tried Shift Right Click, but "Run As" does not show up in the menu.

Comment: Go ahead and start up a command prompt as admin, and try to navigate to the batch file and run it within the elevated command prompt...see if that works.

Comment: @francisswest The batch file runs just fine via cmd prompt (even if I don't RunAs). My question still stands though, especially why Right Click->Edit fails...

Comment: What is your default editing program for text files?  Is it notepad?  Can you open notepad by itself?

Comment: So if you create a new text file on the drive, and then right->click "edit", it will open. If you rename that same file to `.bat` it will not open? What happens if you right click the bat file and choose "open with..." and then pick notepad as the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you posted, the batch file itself is generating the error, not the operating system.  This tells me that something inside of the batch file is trying to access an area that either does not exist, or that you do not have access to.  The other things I am thinking of are that you may have scripts disabled on your computer, or you do not have "execute" access to that file itself.

Comment: Googling the error message he gave, shows it is an OS error.  You write " the batch file itself is generating the error, not the operating system. " <-- So you think that error is written within the batch file, well.. that's a huge presumption you make without checking by asking. And Googling the error  gives this link from MS  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669244/en-gb

Comment: I agree with @barlop here. This looks likes a permissions problem.